# how to send an email to the list of people in daily changing query with python script

Tags: python, email

I have a python script that searches the database and generates the list of people and their responsibilities. The list is changing every day. I need this script to send an email with the search results to every person in this list. Please advice how?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the sendgrid api if you want to e-mail from python. 
https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python

As far as the content (search results), I can't help you without more information, so that's up to you.